# LINQ query needs either ascending or descending in the same query

Tags: c#, linq

Is there anyway this code can be refactored? The only difference is the order by part.

Idealy I'd like to use a delegate/lambda expression so the code is reusable but I don't know how to conditionally add and remove the query operators OrderBy and OrderByDescending

```
var linq = new NorthwindDataContext();

        var query1 = linq.Customers
            .Where(c => c.ContactName.StartsWith("a"))
            .SelectMany(cus=>cus.Orders)
            .OrderBy(ord => ord.OrderDate)
            .Select(ord => ord.CustomerID);

        var query2 = linq.Customers
            .Where(c => c.ContactName.StartsWith("a"))
            .SelectMany(cus => cus.Orders)
            .OrderByDescending(ord => ord.OrderDate)
            .Select(ord => ord.CustomerID);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own reusable extension method which will do this:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IQueryable<TSource> source,
     Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
     bool ascending)
{
     return ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector)
          : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
}
```

and similarly for `ThenBy`:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source,
     Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
     bool ascending)
{
     return ascending ? source.ThenBy(keySelector)
          : source.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
}
```

Comment: Kinda off topic, but will the above translate correctly to Linq2SQL? IOW is it clever enough to see an 'unsupported' method and execute it before it builds a syntax tree and generate the SQL?  Just wondering, never tried it.  :)

Comment: @leppie: It's just calling into the existing Queryable methods - those are what build up the expression tree. Note that this *won't* work against `IEnumerable<T>` at the moment, although you could easily write equivalent extension methods which would.

Comment: Right. I have not really dived into that before. So it executes the 'entire' query to receive a 'syntax tree' to build SQL. Makes sense, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can split your query up into bits, and use control flow logic. LINQ to SQL will magically construct the correct query as if you had typed it all one line! The reason this works is that the query is not sent to the database until you request the data, but instead is stored as an expression.

```
var linq = new NorthwindDataContext();
var query = linq.Customers
    .Where(c => c.ContactName.StartsWith("a"))
    .SelectMany(cus=>cus.Orders);

IOrderedQueryable<Order> query2;
if (useAscending) {
    query2 = query.OrderBy(ord => ord.OrderDate);
} else {
    query2 = query.OrderByDescending(ord => ord.OrderDate);
}

var query3 = query2.Select(ord => ord.CustomerID);
```

Comment: Errorrr!!!!!!!!!  Your ordering needs to happen before select, else you dealing with a different type  :)

Comment: Thanks Mark. Does it matter if the order by query operators are placed after the select() ?

Comment: @leppie: Yeah, sorry I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1):

```
return from T in bk.anbarsabts
       where T.kalaname == str
       orderby T.date descending
       select new { T.date, T.kalaname, T.model, T.tedad };
```

Answer (score 0):

With numbers, etc you can normally just negate the 'ordering variable'.

With `DateTime`, I am not so sure. You could try using a `Timespan`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you have a condition where you decide if the order by is ascending or descending you can use this

```
var query1 = linq.Customers
.Where(c => c.ContactName.StartsWith("a"))
.SelectMany(cus=>cus.Orders)

if(SortAscending)
   query1 = query1.OrderBy(ord => ord.OrderDate);
else
   query1 = query1.OrderByDescending(ord => ord.OrderDate);

var query2 = query1.Select(ord => ord.CustomerID);
```

Comment: See, you made the same mistake as the answer below (it is now fixed).

Comment: @leppie: Not only is it fixed, but it is above now, not below. So your comment is inaccurate and probably more confusing than helpful! Why not just repeat your comment rather than trying to use a reference? In other words, just write this: 'Your ordering needs to happen before select, else you dealing with a different type'. ;-)

Comment: There, fixed it. However I think I prefer jon's answer my self as well ;-)

Comment: @Mark Byers: It is not inaccurate, as you have a different sort order. Mine is default (newest first), so your comment is inaccurate!  :)

Comment: @leppie: Oh, I forgot that the sort order is configurable. I just always have sorted by votes... OK, you win :-P